# How to make a uiviewcontroller flip to next page?

Tags: objective-c

I am using uitapgestures and i want a uiviewcontroller to navigate to another controller with flip animation. I tried using uimodaltransitionflip, it works but the button on the next controller will not be able to work. How do i do this?

For this code, the button works on the other page.

```
- (void)imageView1DoubleTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    GFStoryBoardViewController *gfsb = [[GFStoryBoardViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];



    [self.navigationController pushViewController:gfsb animated:YES];

}
```

For this code the button doesn't Work on the next page

```
- (void)imageView2DoubleTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    SBStoryBoardViewController *sbsb = [[SBStoryBoardViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    sbsb.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:sbsb animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Can you provide us some code. Are you sure that the problem is the flip? Probably the button just does not work on your controller?

Comment: i edited my codes above. please take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a root view controller's view as a container hold the animation. This can be a custom container view controller or the UIWindow. *(ie [UIApplication sharedApplication].window )*

Then do this:

```
 [UIView transitionWithView:rootViewController.view duration:0.40 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^
    {
        [currentViewController.view removeFromSuperView];
        //This will take up the whole screen of the container view. If using UIWindow
        //If using UIWindow, you may need to adjust to accomodate the status bar. 
        newViewController.view.frame = rootViewController.view.bounds 
        [rootViewController.view addSubView:newViewController.view];

    } completion:^(BOOL complete)
    {
         //Anything that you want to happen afterwards
    }];
```